# How to boot a already install linux distribution from vmware?

Tags: vmware-server, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I've installed two systems:window xp and ubuntu.

And `vmware` is installed in windows.

Is it possible to enter `ubuntu` from `vmware`,while of course I'm still in windows?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, your question is like a puzzle - trying to untangle the seemingly random combination of letters into a series of sentences.

It looks like you have installed some version of VMWare (Workstation, Server, Player - which one? which version) installed on top of some version of Windows. The Windows machine may also have a copy of Ubuntu installed on the same disk allowing selection via GRUB - is that right?

If that's right then you can run Ubuntu from it's own partition but it's reasonably hard to do. [THID](http://imrannazar.com/Running-a-Windows-Partition-in-VMware) is a link to a guide on how to get a local Windows partition to run as a VM, the principal is the same but varies obviously, it's the best guide I've come across.

If I've misunderstood your question then I'm afraid you're going to have to rewrite it to make it clear.

Comment: Just edited to clarify.

Comment: not much difference to be honest, does my understanding of the problem sound correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking if it's possible to give direct disk access to a "VM" in VMware that *happens* to already be a "real" install?

If that's the case, then I do not believe it's possible.